# How to deal with URL with spaces in it?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString * urlCached = URL.CacheImageURL;
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlCached];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

It works fine for most URL. However, if URL contains space such as         http://google.com/Hello World.htm then it won't work.

What should I do for such URLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can percent-escape characters which aren't valid inside an URL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
    [urlCached stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This is easy but not always correct; for escaping valid URL special chars (`%`, `&`, `?`, `:`)
as well, use the [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001206-CH1g-F16659) function.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus Read their documentation. The first one won't, the second one will if you ask it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Encode the URL... use %20 instead of the space. For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @H2CO3 How so? It's merely a reference to the encoding table. However your solution is the better one - more generic. I interpreted the question and thought he/she only needed to know how to encode a space for a single url case.